# C++ asynchronous loop

Tags: c++, function, loops, asynchronous

I'm new in asynchronous programming and try to make a simple "mouse listener" in my 'textBox' class.

This is how I tried:

```
void textBox::Listener() {
    while (1) {
            sf::Vector2i position= sf::Mouse::getPosition(window);
            if ((GetKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) & 0x80) != 0) {
                isPressed(position.x, position.y);
            }
    }
}
void textBox::init() {
    std::thread t(&textBox::Listener,this);
    t.join();
}
```

I want to call 'Listener()' function when my 'textBox' object initialized and it should wait for my clicks.

The problem is that i can't use any other functions while my program running because the Listener() function doesn't goes asynchronously

Comment: Whats the problem exactly? Youve explained what you want, and you have an example of what you tried, but you havent told us what went wrong.

Comment: The problem is that i can't use any other functions while my program running because the Listener() function doesn't goes asynchronously

Comment: Do note that `t.join();` is going to wait for the thread to end before it continues.

Comment: @Aron Thats because you .join(). That waits for the thread to finish... (P.S: You should edit your question to specify what the problem is so others dont have to read through the comments)

Comment: P.P.S: This code needs a rethink. Removing the join (which is preventing you from doing async work) would cause you to terminate because the destructor of the thread will be called at the end of init and that will terminate your program (since the thread is joinable). You *could* call detach instead but the thread is referencing an object and if that object dies before your thread terminates you also end up in a lot of trouble. (TL;DR; Multithreading is hard)

Comment: Don't have the loop in Listener.  Trigger listener on the KeyPressed event.

Answer (score 0):

actually i think you can't if the function is not virtual

Answer (score 0):

thread/join are the most basic building blocks of concurrency.

In reality if you want an async event loop you need to either build one or use a ready-made one.

The windows message loop is one such event loop. `boost::asio` provides them, as do many other libraries.

The basic idea is that listeners will post work (a polymorphic function object) onto a work queue which will be executed by an executor (running on some thread or in a thread pool).